Linux 6.5 netfilter NAT reuses TCP ports in TIME_WAIT status?
In my understanding, Linux (netfilter)'s NAT doesn't reuse TCP ports in TIME_WAIT status, but seemingly Linux >= 6.5 reuses TCP ports in TIME_WAIT, even if the destination is the same.
For example, I added this iptables rule.
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 3478 -j SNAT --to-source :10000
Now, only port 10000 is used to connect *:3478 in TCP. I used stunclient (https://www.stunprotocol.org/) for testing (stunserver.stunprotocol.org provides TCP STUN server at port 3478).
In Linux older than 6.5, once I use stunclient, any subsequent requests will continue to fail in 120 seconds (= the default value of net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait).
However, in Linux 6.5 or newer, subsequent requests sometimes succeed shortly after the first request. Strangely, they don't necessarily succeed, but succeed with a probability of 20-30%.
I tested this with following kernel versions.
5.19.0-50
6.2.0-39
6.3 (mainline)
6.4 (mainline)
6.5 (mainline)
6.5.0-14
6.5.0-27
6.8.6 (mainline)

All my tests were conducted on Linux Mint 21.3, with iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables), nft 1.0.2, libnftnl 1.2.1.
Does anyone know the cause of this behavior? I guess this behavior doesn't conform to the purpose of TIME_WAIT.

It could be this commit: netfilter: snat: evict closing tcp entries on reply tuple collision . If you relied on the previous behavior, maybe you could tell more about what you intended to achieve (to avoid an XY problem).

Oh, thank you! Actually, I was basically just curious about what causes this behavior, so your answer is very helpful.
By the way, I have another question now.  Judging from the output of conntrack, the sequence numbers of connections usually increase, but sometimes it decrease (e.g. 2833015883 -> 198677895).
return (__s32)(new->proto.tcp.seen[0].td_end - old->proto.tcp.seen[0].td_end) > 0;

Why this code causes this behavior? And, isn't this behavior problematic (from the viewpoint of TCP protocol)?
